# Error de sitaxis en un UPDATE pero no veo el error

Tags: java, sql

Buenas llevo de pelea desde antes de ayer y abreis visto ya muchos post y este método lleva dado problemas desde puff y mas. os cuento la idea es borrar un departamento y si hay gente reubicarla en otro.

La búsqueda de si hay gente es correcta, si no hay gente lo borra bien. Si hay gente da un error al crear el nuevo departamento. 
El error debugeando este en `SET numDepartamento = '" + numNDepartamento + "' "` pero no se porque:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'numDepto' in 'where clause'
Departamento no encontrado en la base de datos...
```

Ese es el error, ahora os dejo el método que lo he desmenuzado para que sea mas cómodo y para el `main` sea mas factible.

```
public boolean hayGente(int num) {
    boolean hay = false;
    try {
        Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res;
        res = orden.executeQuery("SELECT count(nombrePersona) total FROM persona WHERE numDepartamento ='" + num + "'");
        if (res.next()) {
            hay = res.getInt("total") > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return hay;
}

public boolean borrarDepartamento(Departamento d, int numDepartamento) {
    boolean flag = false;
    boolean existe = false;
    String nombreD = d.getNombre();
    String direccion = d.getDireccion();
    int numNDepartamento = d.getNumDepartamento();

    try {
        if (hayGente(numDepartamento) == true) {
            Statement orden1 = conn.createStatement();
            orden1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO departamento(nombre, direccion, numDepto)  VALUES('"
                    + nombreD + "','" + direccion + "','" + numNDepartamento + "')");
            orden1.close();
            Statement orden5 = conn.createStatement();
            orden5.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");
            orden5.close();
            Statement orden2 = conn.createStatement();
            orden2.executeUpdate("UPDATE persona "
                    + "SET numDepartamento = '" + numNDepartamento + "' "
                    + "WHERE numDepto = " + numDepartamento);
            orden2.close();
            Statement orden3 = conn.createStatement();
            orden3.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM departamento where numDepto =" + numDepartamento);
            orden3.close();
            Statement orden6 = conn.createStatement();
            orden6.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");
            orden6.close();
            flag = true;
        } else {
            Statement orden4 = conn.createStatement();
            orden4.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM departamento where numDepto =" + numDepartamento);
            orden4.close();
            flag = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return flag;
}
```

muchas gracias por todo con esto ya entrego el trabajo

Comment: Siento decirte que ese codigo no tiene sentido.. inserta a una tabla.. insertas a otra tabla.. y borras de la primera tabla? entonces para que insertaste? Y sobre tu error.. el query es correcto..

Comment: Si tiene sentido como queno. Tu buscas si hay gente si hay gente cres un nuevo departamento para meterlos yluego borras el departamento que diste el numero al prinicipio. Si no hay gente eliminas directamente el departamente @gbianchi mira atentamente los if else

Comment: No. no tiene sentido.. si vas a borrar un departamento, que sentido tiene mandarlos a otro??? mejor modifica el que queres "borrar"...  Y ahi mirando atentamente veo que si son dos departamentos distintos.. mejor usar nombres de variable que se entiendan no? como departamentoanterior y departamentonuevo ;) e igual, el update esta al reves ;)

Comment: @gbianchi ya he corregido el update me he dado cuenta. Yo no pongo las normas las pone el profesor y si el dice que se tiene que hacer asi asi se tiene que hacer. ademas es mu cabezon no te pude salir de los parametro que el da

Comment: por información de tu base de datos como el nombre de las tablas, algo me dice que allí está el error

Comment: UPDATE persona "
                    + "SET numDepartamento = '" + numNDepartamento + "' "
                    + "WHERE numDepto = " + numDepartamento) o es numdepartamento o es numdepto.. cual es el campo de **ESA** tabla?

Answer (score 0):

En tu primera `SELECT` sobre la tabla `persona`, en el `WHERE` utilizas un campo que se llama `numDepartamento`. A la hora de hacer el `UPDATE` imagino que tambien tendrás que usar ese mismo nombre de campo (a no ser que tengas dos columnas, `numDepartamento` y `numDpto`).

Como criterio, si tienes un dato que se repite en varias tablas, lo mejor es que utilices el mismo nombre en ambas tablas, te evitaras errores como el que te ha pasado.

Comment: En este caso, como es un error tipografico, la pregunta se cierra por ese motivo. tenes razon tiene problemas con los nombres de campo.

Comment: no es un problema es que dependiendo de la tabla tengo numdpto  o numeroDepartamento cada tabla tiene un nombre cosa del profesor yo le hubiera puesto el mismo